# Как сделать post запрос в код apps script?

Tags: python, google-apps-script

У меня развернут проект в apps script. Я хочу отправлять данные в проект apps script, по api запросу.

Вот я развернул проект в apps script

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня есть api (url веб-приложения)

Как я могу к нему обратиться, что бы передать данные?

Comment: Вам нужно уточнить вопрос. Сейчас на него сложно дать ответ, потому что не понятно, что конкретно Вам нужно сделать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Необходимо использовать зарезервированное слово `doPost` для определения точки входа POST-запроса.

Пример. Пишет в первый лист заданной Таблицы. В теле POST-запроса требует два параметра `name` и `value`

```js
function doPost(e) {
  const res = {
    success: undefined,
  };
  try {
    const { name, value } = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
    const date = new Date();
    const book = SpreadsheetApp.openById('10U5LKQUiektqliOXmBpl4oD1RXaRo_XbZGKWb01dR84');
    const sheet = book.getSheets()[0];
    sheet.appendRow([date, name, value]);
    res.success = true;
  } catch (error) {
    res.success = false;
    res.error = error.message;
  }
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(res));
}
```

Проверка

```bash
$> curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"name":"iam","value":2}' -L https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxbJArNzRl3IdBZgYkfwz0-y8AdPzOh68d7X4hKIDGKTuwBG2ZtO04_GZkGdq0EdZ8L/exec
```

Ответ

```bash
$< {"success":true}
```

Скрипт должен быть опубликован от имени редактора Таблицы для всех в Интернет.